# Why does my WCF Service generate Array types when I explicitly set it to List?

Tags: wcf, list, arrays, service, reference

I have been consuming a service for some time in development, and have been updating my service reference almost daily with no problems. Collection types have been set to generate as System.Collections.Generic.List in the Advanced options.

However, for no apparent reason, now when I update the Service Reference, it's generating Array types for all my collections! It is still configured to generate the List type, why is it all of a sudden going back to the Array type?? I'm using VS 2010..

Comment: Did the serializer change to XmlSerializer by any chance?? I've seen this happen, and with XmlSerializer, I seem to always get arrays no matter what I ask for. With the DataContractSerializer, the List<T> approach works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer. A code change on the service was as follows: a class was marked as Abstract, and used in another class as `List<AbstractClass>`. Generating the service proxy on the client machine (EVEN WITH SVCUTIL.EXE) was forcing all of my list collections to be generated as `Class[]` instead of `List<Class>`. Removing the Abstract from the Class fixed everything and I am able to generate my service proxy from within VS and from the command prompt without issue.